# Type Casting, Operator Precedence or something else?

Tags: java

I was asked to explain why the following snippet prints 1. I have stared at it for a while but not yet able to say why it prints out 1 or even why it does compile. Can someone kindly tell me why?

```
    int i = (byte) + (char) - (int) + (long) - 1;
    System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: I've never seen something like that. Why do you do that?

Comment: It's nothing to do with neither of your assumptions, actually. What you got yourself here is `+-+-1` mixed in with couple of primitive type casts. Ignoring type casting, the expression is equal to doubly inverting signum on an integer (because `+` signs are only parsed as delimiters to the signum inversion)

Comment: I never do that on my own. I was just asked to explain why in an interview for a junior developer job in order to show my java skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a sequence of casts and number/char conversions:

```
int i = (byte) +(char) -(int) +(long) -1;
```

can be made verbose as:

```
int a = -1;
long b = (long) a;
int c = (int) -b; //makes it positive
char d = (char) c;
byte e = (byte) d;
int f = e;

System.out.println(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have here 4 casting operators and 4 +/- operators.

Since +/- can't be applied to casting operators, the only way to evaluate this expression is by treat the `-` and `+` as unary operators :

```
int i = (byte) (+ ((char) (- ((int) (+ ((long) (- 1)))))));
                                                 -1 int
                                          -1 long
                                     -1 long
                              -1 int
                          --1 == +1 int
                    1 char
               1 char
        1 byte
1 int
```